# How can I run my test cases (which written in junit 3.x and 4.x) using jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, junit

I want to run my all test cases which is written in both junit versions(3.x & 4.x) in JSP. If I called that jsp it should run all test cases. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

This being odd, there is a way to do it:

You can use [`JUnitCore.runClasses(..)`](http://api.dpml.net/junit/4.2/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html), where you pass an array of the classes of your unit tests.

Of cours, you will need a `<@% page import="org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" %>` in your jsp.

Still, tell us your scenario, because this doesn't seem quite right. At least do this in a `Servlet`, not a jsp